# displaying the database and creating the database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to display the database with 3 columns latitude,longitude and addresss. i tried using cursors but the application crashes. i am writing the listener for button in onlocationchanged method. the button is save geopoint it updates the latitude,longitude and address of user. i also have a button named find geopoint which is used to display the database. here is my code. i wrote this in onlocationchanged.

```
  try{
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Geo_Create_Table+" (Latitude INTEGER,Longtitude INTEGER ,ID INTEGER);");

     }
     catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try{
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Geo_Create_Table +" VALUES (" +lat +"," +lon +","+1+");");


    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

and i used cursor to display the database but the problem persists pls help

Comment: Can you provide the logcat for the crash.  Where in the app is the issue happening?  From just the information provided, it looks like you're trying to insert a double (latitude and longitude) into a column who's data type is set to and INTEGER.  This will cause a problem.  Try changing INTEGER to double.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Geo_Create_Table+" (Latitude INTEGER,Longtitude INTEGER ,ID INTEGER)");

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Geo_Create_Table +" VALUES (" +lat +"," +lon +","+1+")");
```

Comment: did you just copy part of the question?

Comment: No.removing ';' that causing problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using execSQL, rather the insert method.

Your request should include '?', and the values should be added as parameters

Are you sure the lat and lon are integers?

The proper way to declare an Integer column in sqlite is NUMERIC

You should let sqlite handle the ID part itself

Also, if you run CREATE TABLE twice, it will crash. Run CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS if you must.

What is the exception you get exactly?